# Validating POJO with JSR 303

Tags: java, spring, jsr

I have a POJO as follows:

```
public class ClosureCodeReasonRequest {
    @NotNull(message = MessageConstants.CLOSURE_CODE_BLANK_ERROR)
    @NotBlank(message = MessageConstants.CLOSURE_CODE_BLANK_ERROR)
    private String closureCode;

    @NotNull(message = MessageConstants.REASON_TITLE_BLANK_ERROR)
    @NotBlank(message = MessageConstants.REASON_TITLE_BLANK_ERROR)
    @Size(max = 50, message = MessageConstants.REASON_TITLE_TOO_LONG)
    private String reasonTitle;

    @NotEmpty
    private List<String> programList;

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    private String isActive;

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    private Long version;
}
```

In the above POJO, value of `isActive` can be either "true" or "false" and length of `programList` can be either 1 or 2 and contents will be among "Test1" and "Test2".

Is there any built in annotation that can be used for these requirements or do I have to create a new one?

Comment: Any reason why the code is not `private boolean active` instead of `private String isActive`? `@Size(min = 1, max = 2) private List<String> programList` will work for the second requirement. JSR-303 does not have any mechanism for validating the content of a `Collection`. You will have to write a custom validator for validating the collection content.

Answer (score 0):

What about using [@Pattern](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html)?

for isActive you could use `@Pattern(regexp="(true|false)")` 
for programList you could use `@Size(2)` with `@Pattern(regexp="(Test1|Test2)`?

I didn't tested that, but you can do it on your own.